# Designing a database with several different kinds of products?

Tags: database, database-design

As part of a recent project I have started planning out, I am required to build the structure of a database which will contain several products. As an example, think of the way Amazon is structured. It has several categories and within those categories, several sub-categories.

My problem is that conceptually I am unsure on how to build the database tables. I have thought of creating a self-referencing table for the categories and sub-categories, but since I do plan to have a wide variety of products within the database, I don't know if I should just group them into one table called "Products" or put them all in separate tables.

For example, a toilet would be one product while a television could be another. Even though they have different categories/sub-categories, they are both products. By placing them in one "Products" table, they would share attributes that would make no sense for both of them. A toilet would not need an attribute for resolution or display size(unless it is a very special toilet?) and a television wouldn't need a seat size attribute.

I thought that one to get around this and still keep everything in one table would be to create a bunch of NOT NULL attributes that could be missing for certain items if they weren't necessary, but common sense is telling me that this is probably not the best way to go about things.

So at this point, I feel that my real problem is figuring out how to structure this database and its tables with several categories/sub-categories and different kinds of items. Would I create a table for televisions and a table for toilets? How would this all be structured? How are these sort of problems normally planned out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a design decision than anything else.

This is how I would separate the tables:

`categories` (e.g. household)

`sub_categories` (e.g. bathroom is a foreign key of household)

`products` (e.g. Ceramic toilet)

As for the extra attributes, you can either store these directly within the products table or create another table called `products_extra_attributes` and store an optional NULL value within the `products` table which would be a foreign key pointing toward the additional attributes for the individual product.

Make sense? I'll make an edit later on if not as I'm answering this question from my phone.

Comment: Ok I think this is making sense. So I would have general attributes for all products in a "Products" table and a foreign key to another table "ExtraAttributes" (named something like that) where each row in ExtraAttributes would have properties for different products, such as toilets or televisions. Does that sound right?

Comment: You got it :) Depending on the scale of your products catalog - you're better off doing things this way as you'd only be joining tables if a product has additional attributes (determined by that additional foreign key value within the products table, as you figured).

Answer (score 2):

A generic products table is a good way to go. You're not going to want to create a new table in your schema every time you have a new type of product.

Similar with the categories, a self referencing table is better with a parent/child relationship so you don't have to create a new table each time you want a new level of sub-category.

Your products table should contain information that's common amongst all your products. E.g. name and possibly price (although if you have different prices for an individual product, then price is best stored in another table that references the product).

If you have a bunch of other information that relates to characteristics for each product, then maybe create an attributes table and another table that references each attribute's value for that product.

Here's a simple example schema:

[image]

Comment: Nice. Just an observation on your diagram. Why not leave out the categories table and add its properties (id, parent_id, name) to the category_product table?

Comment: @fat_mike The above schema works well when you have products that exist in multiple categories. It also avoids duplicating data, e.g. the category name, each time you add a product to a category (because each record will need a category name property).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how many products. If you only sold toilets and televisions I'd say go ahead and make totally separate tables for them, however if you have 100s of different product types all of which would have different attributes I might suggest creating a products table that stored common attributes (they all have a cost and, probably, a size) then a product type table that specifies a set of attributes for each product type, then a attributes table to define the attributes and lat a product values table.

So for example, take a Sony TV. It would be in products with the price and a link to the product type, which would be TV. That would one to many join to attributes that all TVs had and Sony TV would have entries in the product values for each of those attributes. This way, you wouldn't have to redefine shared attributes, so when you started selling other things that had resolution, you could just add them to the product type.

Make sense?