# How To Design A Database With Different Types of Products

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have a store that currently sells three different types of items: Video Game, Console, and Cables. I am trying to figure out how to design a single table that would be used by these three items.

I was thinking that each type would have the following properties:

```
Video Game
- name
- console

Console
- name

Cable
- name
```

I came up with the design:

```
Product
- Type
- Name
- Console
```

So it would translate into something like:

```
id | type    | name          | console
---+---------+---------------+---------
 1 | game    | Goldeneye     | N64
 2 | console | SNES          | null
 3 | cable   | HDMI          | null
 4 | game    | Smash Bros    | Wii
```

But the console column would always be null for `console` and `cable` typed products. Furthermore, I think this design can be very restrictive if I decide to sell another type of product that requires another column (ie - TV monitors and include screen size).

Is there a better way to design my table?

I looked around on SO and this solution seemed ideal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20793237/1054937. I would create a generic Product table that references an Attribute table. In that case the DB would not be able to enforce the Attirbutes (ie - all games must have a console attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a polymorphic association with Products table.

Have a generic Product table which will have item_type and item_id:

```
id | item_type      | item_id
 1 | VideoGame      | 1
 2 | Console        | 1  
 3 | Cable          | 1  
 4 | VideoGame      | 2
```

VideoGames table:

```
id | name          | price
 1 | Goldeneye     |  59
 2 | FIFA19        |  88
```

Consoles Table:

```
id | name          | price
 1 | SNES          |  200
 2 | WhateverName  |  300
```

Cables Table

```
id | name          | price
 1 | HDMI          |  20
 2 | CAT6          |  30
```

Now every product is available in Products table and you can get exact product by with the help of `item_id` and `item_type`.

Here Product with id=4 is actually the video game named `FIFA19` and all the corresponding details for it can be found from the `Consoles` table like it's price is 88.

So basically you just have to query Products table for an item based on it's type and id and you'll reach that record.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily have two tables

```
1. Product
2. Attributes
```

Table structures could be like this

```
Product
id | type    | name         
---+---------+---------------
 1 | game    | Goldeneye     
 2 | console | SNES          
 3 | cable   | HDMI          
 4 | game    | Smash Bros    
 5 | TV      | LG

Attributes
id | product_id | type        | value        
---+------------+-------------+---------
 1 | 1          | console     | N64
 2 | 4          | console     | Wii   
 3 | 5          | screen size | 50"
```

Let me know if this solves your problem